# How to show entries of custom entity as options for a selector in frontend in Shopware 5?

Tags: shopware

I have created a custom entity Model with it's model and ext.js app as well. It lets me to create new entities in shopware backend as it is described here:

https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/backend-components/listing/

I then linked the entry to the s_user with s_user_attributes table as it is shown here:

https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/attribute-system/

```
$crud->update('s_user_attributes', 'recommendedStream', 'single_selection', [
'displayInBackend' => true,
'label' => 'Recommended stream',
'entity' => 'Shopware\Models\ProductStream\ProductStream',
```

This let's me to select the entity and see the list of all those entities in a selector in backend settings of a customer.

I want to know what is the easies and correct way to have a selector for user attributes with options as all the entries which can be created in backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you want to show that selector.
The most common way is to expand template view data (you can use your entity repository to findAll() records.
E.g. you can subscribe on `Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Frontend_Account` event if you wnat to show that selector in the customer account after that in the subscribed method you need to extend view data like

```
 public function onFrontendPostDispatchAssignViewData(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
{
    /** @var \Enlight_Controller_Action $controller */
    $controller = $args->get('subject');
    $view = $controller->View();
   
    $view->assign('productStreams', Shopware()->Container()->get('models')->getRepository(ProductStream::class)->findAll();
   
}
```

Now you should get `productStreams` in a template. You can extend the theme template now to show input, and probably you need to extend the save process to save the selected value into your new attribute.

Comment: Usually I was assigning the variable by getting the content from the model's table by sql directly. Is the usage of repository better?

Comment: Using Doctrine is more convenient than raw sql, in my opinion. And it is more native to shopware. I have no critical objections against raw sql. But using of doctrine entities is more clear than arrays.